# Is this a correct way to parse incoming JSON over websocket, and respond depending on the type of message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ocpp

So I am receiving JSON over a websocket from a chargepoint using OCPP 1.6 JSON.
I am trying to parse the message and respond appropriately, depending on what the message is, using Node.js

Here is the message that I recieve:

```
[ 2,
  'bc7MRxWrWFnfQzepuhKSsevqXEqheQSqMcu3',
  'BootNotification',
  { chargePointVendor: 'AVT-Company',
    chargePointModel: 'AVT-Express',
    chargePointSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1',
    chargeBoxSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1.01',
    firmwareVersion: '0.9.87',
    iccid: '',
    imsi: '',
    meterType: 'AVT NQC-ACDC',
    meterSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1.01' } ]
```

In this case it is the 'BootNotification' message, to which I need to respond with an 'Accepted' message.

Here is my code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

    //Make incoming JSON into javascript object
    var msg = JSON.parse(message)

    // Print whole message to console
    console.log(msg)

    // Print only message type to console. For example BootNotification, Heartbeat etc...
   console.log("Message type: " + msg[2])

    // Send response depending on what the message type is
    if (msg[2] === "BootNotification") {
      //Send correct response

    } // Add all the message types

  });


});
```

With this I get the message type printed to the console as a string:

```
Message type: BootNotification
```

So my question is that is this the correct way to get the type of the message? 
I am new to this so I want to make sure.

The specification for OCPP 1.6 JSON is available here: [OpenChargeAlliance website](https://www.openchargealliance.org/downloads/)

Comment: Can you please tell which npm package you used for connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess YES. `JSON.parse` is the built-in to, well, pares JSON strings. In case that goes wrong it throws an error, so you might `try/catch` this.

Since the response you get is an array, there is no other way as to access its items with a numeric index.

---

In such cases I personally prefer to have something like that:

```
const handlers = {
  'BootNotification': request => { 'msg': 'what a request' }
};
```

Than you can:

```
let respone = {'msg': 'Cannot handle this'}

if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(msg[2])) {
  response = handlers[msg[2]](msg);

}
```

But that is just the way I would go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about OCPP message structure (*not parsing a JSON*), I can provide you the details about OCPP 1.6 version.

In OCPP 1.6, the **client** (*Charging Station*) sends a **CALL** (similar to request in HTTP) to **server** (*Charging Station Management Systems*). All CALLs have a strict structure of 4 elements:

- **MessageTypeId** (*integer*)
- **UniqueId** (*UUID, string*)
- **Action** (*string*)
- **Payload** (*JSON object containing the arguments relevant to the Action.*)

or as in your example:

```
[
  2,
  'bc7MRxWrWFnfQzepuhKSsevqXEqheQSqMcu3',
  'BootNotification',
  { chargePointVendor: 'AVT-Company',
    chargePointModel: 'AVT-Express',
    chargePointSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1',
    chargeBoxSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1.01',
    firmwareVersion: '0.9.87',
    iccid: '',
    imsi: '',
    meterType: 'AVT NQC-ACDC',
    meterSerialNumber: 'avt.001.13.1.01' } 
]
```

So the Type of Action should be always at index of 2 (*as you retrieve it when you parse received message*). You can refer to @philipp anwser on way how to handle an errors when parsing.

Comment: I have to implement same thing. Can you please help and provide me some documentation to read.

Comment: Nothing particular really. Good example in Python is https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp . I suggest you read it and try it in some simple form to understand. Also, OCPP documentation on their site is a must read to understand https://www.openchargealliance.org .

Comment: I have to implement using Node JS.

Comment: Where can I find MessageTypeId? Can you Please guide me?